# Are there any historical examples of Binitarianism?

Tags: church-history, binitarian

This is a term I coined myself (and do not advocate) but within Christian history most if not all of the ways someone could be a Trinitarian heretic found historical expression. I'm wondering if there are any who would acknowledge that there is one essence and two persons: the Father and the Son and that each of the persons have a spirit or the essence has a single spirit that is not a person.

Again, for clarity, I believe this would be heresy, but I am surprised that I have never heard anyone advocate this position as it seems like a selective reading of the relevant passages could get you there just as well as any of the other Trinitarian heresies.

Comment: Because the other question is present-focused, I think this question can remain open.

Comment: Yes exactly. The other question is focused on denominations (essentially a modern framework for Christian religious groups currently in practice). Arianism is a historical Trinitarian heresy, but the Jehovah's Witness are a modern denomination/sect that practice a form of Arianism. I'm less interested in modern practitioners as I am in the historical question of whether such a doctrine has ever been articulated.